# How get data from mongodb into react router to render on page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, reactjs, monk

I have an existing blog and I want to move to react. My production blog uses node, express, and mongodb. I followed this [guide](https://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-react-universal-blog-app-a-step-by-step-guide/) to get up and running with react. I think I can use the pages I've setup to grab data from mongo with a request like `https://domain.com/api/all-documents` for the homepage. How can I add an API request to the react router in the `app.get('*',(req, res)` section from the guide's `app-server.js` file?

I want to add something like:

```js
const db = require('monk')('localhost/myDB')
const documents= db.get('documents')
db.close()

app.get('/api/all-documents',function(req,res){
  documents.find({}, {}, function(err, docs) {
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

Then in my react pages I can use the JSON data to add content to the page ... right?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `react-router`s `match`? If so, just put `documents.find(...` inside that.